# Determine clicked object in a scrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have populated a vertical scroll view with a potentially long vertical linear layout consisting of "profiles" present on the device, like so:

```
for (Profile profile : Profiles) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View profileCard = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector, null);

    ...

    profileList.addView(profileCard);
}
```

In the `selector` layout, I have provided an onClick method: so if you click on one of the profiles, the onClick method gets run. However, I want to specifically select that particular profile: how can I return the value of which element was clicked in the scrollView?

Comment: where is click event and rest of the code?provide some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way

```
for (final Profile profile : Profiles) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View profileCard = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector, null);

            /*
             *your code  
             */


            profileCard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Profile clickdProfile = profile;

                }
            });

            profileList.addView(profileCard);
        }
```

**NOTE :** Do not provide onclick in layout file.

Comment: Just realized I could do this, if I'm using the enhanced for loop instead of the for(int i=...), how can I retrieve the index of the Profile I am currently at in Profiles?

Comment: why you need index. profile you getting in onclick is clicked profile.

Comment: Sorry, following through with this, is there a similar method I can invoke for when a user swipes one of the entries?